# Why the distribution $1/(n+1), ..., n/(n+1)$ is used in quantile-quantile plot?

Tags: qq-plot

Why the distribution $1/(n+1), ..., n/(n+1)$ is used in quantile-quantile plot?

Where has this come from?

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember the ECDF (Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function)?

At Non-Parametric statistics you can use it in order to estimate the distribution for some data (under the null hypothesis). It's a step function that jumps up by 1/n at each of the n data points if you don't considerate ties, but a more general definition is

$\hat{{ F }_{ n }(x)}=\begin{cases} 0\quad if\quad x<{ X }_{ (1) } \\ \frac { k }{ n } \quad if\quad { X }_{ (k) }\le x<{ X }_{ (k+1) } \\ 1\quad if\quad x\ge { X }_{ (n) } \end{cases}$

Or maybe $\mathbb{P}(X\le x_{i})=\frac{k}{n+1}$, where k is the ordered number of the statistic

After get these scores, you must find the standarized scores for these estimated CDF values for a normally distributed data, using the N(0,1); and plotting the $z(\frac{k}{n+1})$, i.e., the values you'd expect to get from a N(0,1)